# Adding an element to a list of tuples (Python)

Tags: python, tuples

Implementing the recursive definition of Grays Code from Knuth I need to add values to tuples, I have:

```
In [54]: tuple_one = (1,0,0)

In [55]: tuple_one
Out[55]: (1, 0, 0)

In [56]: tuple_one += (1,)

In [57]: tuple_one
Out[57]: (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

However if I try and assign the above I get a syntax error

```
In [63]: B = tuple_one += (1,)
  File "<ipython-input-63-537be8a059fc>", line 1
    B = tuple_one += (1,)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this ?
Regards Paul

Comment: `B = tuple_one += (1,)` really is invalid syntax. Try `B = tuple_one + (1,)`

Comment: A tuple is immutable in Python. If you want to add items, consider a list (that you can then `append` to).

Comment: @BartoszKP hence I did not put this as an answer. I am merely suggesting that the OP considers a different data structure, as creating multiple tuple objects is less efficient than modifying a single list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a list of tuples.  Its just a tuple.

And the reason it doesn't work is because it is actually invalid syntax.  It is literally equal to

```
B = tuple_one = tuple_one + (1,)
```

if you want to save the value of tuple_one then do it in two line

```
tuple_one += (1,)
B = tuple_one
```

if you don't then just use the `+` operator

```
B = tuple_one + (1,)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it's not a list but wanted to get it to work on an element of the list before looking at the whole list. Cheers Paul

Answer (score 2):

[Explanation from Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)

An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal assignment statements) is **evaluated only once**. An augmented assignment expression like x += 1 can be rewritten as x = x + 1 to achieve a similar, **but not exactly equal effect**. In the augmented version, x is only evaluated once.

> Also, when possible, the actual operation is performed *in-place*, meaning that rather than creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object is modified instead.

With the **exception of assigning to tuples and multiple targets in a single statement**, the assignment done by augmented assignment statements is handled the same way as normal assignments

So, while assigning to tuples or/and multiple targets in a single statement, do not use augmented assignment statements.

Instead, use

```
B = tuple_one = tuple_one + (1,)
```

Comment: Why is `x` evaluated twice in a `x = x + 1` statement -- in other words what's the purpose of the second evaluation?

Comment: Because until the expression is evaluated, the python interpreter doesn't know if the variable/object after assignment expression is x or y or something else. i.e it can be x = x + 1 or x = y + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your "list of tuples" is not a list of tuples, it is a single one. You can tell that it isn't a list, because **there are no square brackets (`[]`)**.

`+=` is used to modify in place, so `a+=1` would be used instead of `a = a+1`. The difference is that `a+1` **returns** the value of `a` plus `1`, but `+=1` does not return anything:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> x = a+=1 #DOES NOT WORK
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = a+=1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> x = a+1
>>> x
2
>>>
```

Here is your edited line:

```
B = tuple_one + (1,)
```